# Multidimensional decision variable python docplex

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, mathematical-optimization, cplex, docplex

To solve my inventory problem I need a three-dimensional decision variable `x_{ij}^t`

I am new to the CPLEX Python API docplex and all I found so far is

```
m = Model(name='inventory_problem')
x = m.integer_var_matrix(keys1=all_origins, keys2=all_destinations)
```

which would cover i and j in the indeces but how can I include the third dimension?

I guess it is not very difficult but I just cannot find it ...
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from using integer_var_cube() you can use integer_var_dict():

```
x = m.integer_var_dict((i, j, t) for i in ... for j in ... for t in ...)
```

With that you can then neatly reference as x[i,j,t]. This also extends to more than 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now I found it ...

apparently there is another function

```
m.integer_var_cube(keys1, keys2, keys3)
```